# Elements hidden from view for no apparent reason

Tags: html, css

I am createing some what of a hub to edit the settings on my server, however the elements within the content are not being shown.

When inspecting the elements the height and width is set to 0;

Here is what the page is displaying:
[image]

And here is what it should show (Html version and it does not show):

```
<div id="forums-content">
                    <div class="main-content">
                    <h2>Update Options</h2>

         <p>Update Failed!</p>
         <hr>
         <p>The option main-settings-use-notice failed to change to main-settings-use-notice.</p>
         <p>Possible issues:</p>
         <ul>
             <li>The option does not exist.</li>
             <li>The option was already equal to what you wanted to change it to.</li>
             <li>The chosen option was been protected therefor you cannot change it.</li>
         </ul>
         <hr>
         <p>Debug:</p>
         <ul>
             <li>Checking to see if the option was already equal to the new setting:</li>
             <li>Solved; the requested option was already set!</li>
         </ul>

                        </div>
                </div>
```

Here is the CSS file:

http://etreecycle.co.uk/hub/CSS/styles.css

It's a little messy because I have been playing around with it.

Sorry about the screen shots, the page is in a restricted area.

How can I allow all elements to display as 'normal'?

Comment: Don't screenshot your code : build a relevant example here (using the snippet) to allow us to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Have you tried validating your code: https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: @kojow7 Only keyframe and calculation errors: http://goo.gl/Xqv6Ye

Comment: Did you validate your HTML code as well, or just your CSS?

Comment: @kojow7 Just did, the only error was an extra </p> which was set in the options page, fixing now. However I don't think this is the cause of the issue.

Comment: @kojow7 Removed the extra element, the problem is still there.

Comment: The code you posted works fine. There is something else, perhaps some more CSS?

Comment: @DavidG I am loading the following fonts:   <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Righteous' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

Comment: No, it still works without issue.

Comment: @DavidG Probelm solved; see answers. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing font-size: 0; in your #content section and see what happens. Without your complete code it is hard to see exactly what is going on, but this is the first place I would look.

Comment: Thank you, I don't know how I missed that. This would explain why ony styled elements were showing.

Comment: After applying the change the sidebar has been pushed below the content, know how I can stop this? EDIT: I've made the sidebar absolote and it hides when the page is too small, that should sort it.

Comment: Make sure that the sidebar and the content regions do not take up more than 100% of the parent container.